# Datepicker setDate doesn't work anymore?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

can you explain me why this code :

http://jsfiddle.net/3qJx9/7/

doesn't work ?

I used to use it in order to put the current date as default when no date were loaded, but it doesn't work anymore, and I don't understand why.

Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only call methods on an initialized jQuery UI widget and you forgot to initialize the datepicker:

```
$("#date").datepicker();
$("#date").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Daff/3qJx9/8/)

Comment: Thanks !
But I have a problem with this on my real webpage :
Since the textfield isn't present on the page when it loads, I use a live/focus event to put a datepicker on it.

And thanks to you, I now know that the problem comes from the fact that the datepicker isn't initialized when I try to set the current date, since it waits for the focus to occur...

Am I forced to drop my live event and initialize the datepicker manually when the textfield is created ?

Comment: If you can you should initialize it at the text field creation. The focus event would also work if you check before if the datepicker is initialized yet (*if(§.isFunction($('myfield').datepicker())*).